# How to see if a widget exists in Tkinter?

Tags: python, button, listbox, tkinter

Now, I know that you can check to see if a window exists by:

```
x.winfo_exists()
```

which returns a Boolean. More exactly, I need to check the existence of my buttons, labels, list boxes, sliders etc. Then what?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you know you can call `winfo_exists` to determine if a widget exists, but you don't know how to tell if _your_ widgets exist?

Comment: NO, to see if a window exists. I didn't know it also worked for widgets until I got this answer. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`winfo_exists` returns 1 unless you have destroyed the widget, in which case it returns 0. This method can be called on any widget class, not only the Tk root or Toplevels. Alternatively, you can get all the children of a widget with `winfo_children`:

```
>>> import Tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world")
>>> label.winfo_exists()
1
>>> root.winfo_children()
[<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x0000000002ADC1C8>]
>>> label.destroy()
>>> label.winfo_exists()
0
>>> root.winfo_children()
[]
```

Comment: In case that you didn't returned frame object to "root" (or directly not being created from it) you will not be able to do `label.destroy()`, but u still can search and iterate over `root.winfo_children()` list. As example, `root.winfo_children()[0].destroy()` or `root.winfo_children()[1].destroy()` in case you have a Menu at top. Anyway it's more easy to create handles for every frame you use, plus insert every button/label/etc inside a main frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can also print the type i.e.. type(label). This can be helpful to provide not only existence, but also find if anything is coming up 'NoneType' without an error. The type() will tell you if you have an instance, or other type that can provide valuable clues as to how close the program is performing or returning items to what you think you are asking!  The object.winfo_exists() and object.winfo_children is specific, and will throw an error if the object is not a type 'instance'.

Comment: [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)