# See if Tkinter widget exists (not using .winfo_exists)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to see if a Tkinter widget exists so I can delete it if it does.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311698/tkinter-how-to-see-if-a-widget-exists-in-tkinter?rq=1) on this site uses `widget.winfo_exists` but this returns `1` even if the widget has not been created and only returns `0` if the widget has been destroyed:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
print label.winfo_exists() # returns 1
```

and:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#label = tk.Label(root)
print label.winfo_exists() # also returns 1
```

whereas:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.destroy()
print label.winfo_exists() # returns 0
```

I was trying to use it in this manner:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
# label may exist
if label.winfo_exists() == 1:
    label.destroy() # doesn't work
```

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect `NameError` in your second case. Also, what is the problem if you try to re-`destroy` a widget?

Comment: If a widget hasn't been created, how is it possible for you to call `winfo_exists` on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your observation that `winfo_exists()` returns `1` for a widget that has not been created is wrong. The rules of python absolutely prevent your scenario from behaving that way.

To wit:

```
$ python -i
Python 2.7.6 (default, Dec  2 2013, 11:20:48) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> print label.winfo_exists()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'label' is not defined
>>>
```

The above is exactly what I would expect. You can't possibly get `winfo_exists` to return `1` in this scenario.

The correct answer to "how do I determine if a widget exists" is to use `winfo_exists`. That is the correct way. It will always work assuming the object is or was an instance of a Tkinter widget class.

Comment: Yes it appears I was very confused. When I double checked I must have made a mistake! Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 5):

It appears you are getting confused between the Python variable that holds the reference to the Tk widget and the Tk window itself. `winfo_exists` returns true only if the Tk widget has a window. The python variable may continue to exist after you have destroyed the widget and in this case will return false for `winfo_exists`.

As the Tk destroy function does not throw an error if called for a widget that is already destroyed, you should just be able to call it without any checks. However, you do need to have a value python variable that originally held a Tk widget.

The following interactive session should show this in action:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> label = Label(root)
>>> label.destroy()
>>> label
<tkinter.Label object at 0x02B88310>
>>> label.destroy()
>>> label.winfo_exists()
0
```

In this sample, the label widget is created and destroyed immediately. This leaves a python object on which we can call `winfo_exists` and it correctly returns false. Note also that `label.destroy()` was called twice with no ill effects.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used `try / except`, and `except: pass` is typically frowned upon but it works here.

```
try:
    label.destroy()
except (NameError, AttributeError):
    pass
```

Also:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#label = tk.Label(root)
print label.winfo_exists() # also returns 1
```

This will not return 1 as `label` is not definied, so it can't possibly have a `winfo_exists()`.

Comment: You could at least be more explicit on the `except` - what gets thrown if `label` can't be `destroy`ed?

Comment: Well he could either hit `NameError` or `AttributeError` depending on the situation... it's really meant to be a catch all if he wanted to simply `destroy()` the widget if it's possible to.

Comment: Then it should probably be `except (NameError, AttributeError)`, or at **absolute minimum** `except Exception`, to avoid interfering with e.g. `KeyboardInterrupt`.