# Doctest for non-simple functions and classes

Tags: python, doctest

In a school assignment I'm forced to write doctest for every function, method, and class in my program.

I understand the general principle of doctesting simple functions, such as

```
def square(x)
    return x**2
```

But my functions are not as simple. How, for instance do I write doctest for a function that generates GUI. It takes a list as an argument, prints the list via Tkinter.Text, creates 2 buttons, both of which have callback commands. Function looks like this

```
def createGraphics(list): 
    master = Tk()
    output = Text(master, height = 7, width = 45)
    output.insert(INSERT, list)
    answer = Entry(master)
    label = Label(master, text="Filler text")
    b1 = Button(master, text="B1", command=functionOne)
    b2 = Button(master, text="B2", command=functionTwo)
    output.pack()
    label.pack()
    answer.pack()
    b1.pack()
    b2.pack()
    master.mainloop()
```

This also makes me wonder how I write doctest for functionOne and functionTwo?

Comment: Are you being asked to write doctests for your `createGraphics` function for your assignment or is this question more hypothetical?  Doctests are not really designed to test this type of function. See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/GUI_Testing) for some resources that discuss techniques for  GUI testing (it's focus is PyQt not Tkinter but a lot of the same principles apply)

Comment: @bunji I've been tasked to write doctest for "all classes, functions and methods of your program" so this is not a hypothetical

Comment: Well you could do something like return [whether your `master` window exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311698/how-to-see-if-a-widget-exists-in-tkinter) and have doctest check for that. However, asking for a doctest example for this sort of function really does seem strange to me. If it were me, I'd probably go talk to your professor (or teaching assistant) and ask them to clarify what their expectations are for these types of functions.